# Windows Powershell renaming files not writing Files

Tags: powershell, rename

Hi i'm trying to rename every file in a folder, I want to increase the number by one and it does already tell me that its working in terminal, but it does not write the operation.

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Descending | Rename-Item -WhatIf -NewName {
$name = $_.Name
$matches = [regex]::matches($name,'\d+')
$offset = 0
foreach ($group in $matches.groups)
{
$before = $name.substring(0,$group.Index+$offset)
$after = $name.substring($offset+$group.Index+$group.Length)
$number = (1+$group.Value).toString().PadLeft($group.Length,'0')
$name = $before + $number + $after
$offset = $offset + $number.Length - $group.Length
}
$name
}
```

[image][image]

As you can see in the explorer it does not rename the files, but it does somehow process all of them.

Comment: Is the `-WhatIf` there to show us what it would have done? Lol

Comment: @midi While SO appreciates [self-answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), it is [not apropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387723/11942268) to edit the answer into the question, especially when masking the original, erroneous code by doing so. That's why I rolled back your edit.

Comment: Ok, thx  @stackprotector. I'm new to powershell.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `-WhatIf`, the terminal is giving you the results without performing the operation because of it.

Answer (score 2):

If I got it right something like this should be enough actually:

```
Get-ChildItem | 
Sort-Object -Descending |
ForEach-Object {
    $_.BaseName -match '\d+' | Out-Null
    $Number = $matches[0] -as [int]
    $NewName = $_.BaseName -replace '\d+', $($Number +1)
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($NewName + $_.Extension)
}
```